# PostgreSQL copy command not creating the file specified

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to export some data from my PostgreSQL tables via CLI using the following:

```
\COPY (SELECT * FROM table-name limit 5) TO '"C:\Users\filepath\filename.csv"' WITH CSV DELIMITER ',';
```

It spits out "COPY 5" so it appears to have succeeded, but the file is never created or modified at the location specified. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: Here's what I get when I run select version();   PostgreSQL 9.5.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit -- Running on Vagrant, for what it's worth.

Comment: You are running on Linux but the file path is a Windows path?

Comment: Thanks @ClodoaldoNeto. I'm on a PC running windows, but the Vagrant installation is different. I realized after your comment that I was giving it the wrong path. Rather than 'C:\Users\filepath\filename.csv' I just needed '/vagrant/filename.csv', where 'vagrant' is my root.

Answer (score 0):

Tried and tested works fine

```
postgres=# select * from version();

version    
 PostgreSQL 9.4.8 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

**With headers**

```
COPY (SELECT * from test limit 1) TO '/var/lib/pgsql/mycsv1.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

**Without headers**

```
COPY (SELECT * from test limit 1) TO '/var/lib/pgsql/mycsv2.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

All the best